# Error linking my svm.cpp file using LIBSVM with my C program

Tags: c, machine-learning, linker, linker-errors, libsvm

I am trying to use the LIBSVM package on Eclipse IDE using C.

In the README file, it states that "You need to #include "svm.h" in your C/C++ source files and
link your program with `svm.cpp'."

I already included "svm.h" in all my source files and I added my 'svm.cpp' file under the source code folder. However, I got an error "template with C linkage" in the 'svm.cpp' file.

Does the error have anything to do with the way I added the 'svm.cpp' file in my program? I really do not understand and I tried searching everywhere.

svm.cpp:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include "libsvm.h"
#include "main.h"


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int libsvm_version = LIBSVM_VERSION;
typedef float Qfloat;
typedef signed char schar;


#ifndef min
    template <class T> static inline T min(T x,T y) { return (x<y)?x:y; }
#endif


#ifndef max
    template <class T> static inline T max(T x,T y) { return (x>y)?x:y; }
#endif


template <class T> static inline void swap(T& x, T& y) { T t=x; x=y; y=t; }
template <class S, class T> static inline void clone(T*& dst, S* src, int n)

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of libsvm you are using, and where did you download it from?

[This version](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r94100/libsvm-2.8/svm.cpp) of `svm.cpp` does *not* have `extern "C"` around templates.

If you added them yourself, you have no-one else to blame.

If your version came with `extern "C"`, that version is broken: templates really can't have `extern "C"` linkage.

**Update:**

> I added the extern "C" by myself because I thought it was necessary. Is it wrong?

Yes, it is.

> when I did not add extern "C", there were more errors

You should accept this answer to your question, remove your modifications, and ask a new question detailing the other errors.

Comment: I used the version which you linked, but I added the extern "C" by myself because I thought it was necessary. Is it wrong? Because when I did not add extern "C", there were more errors, such as: "undefined reference to '_Heap_Begin' " etc... Is there anyway to resolve this issue?